# concurrent READ and WRITE on MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

If a table is frequently written from front end and same table has to be as frequently searched as well. Both are performance critical.

For example a POST table which is searchable having Full Text index on its "**content**" column ? If few users are writing posts, it goes to same table and then other users will  search on table same time for keywords.

```
Will UPDATE/INSERT operation lock SELECT queries in above case ?
```

database - MySQL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This depends on the Storage Engine of the Table

## [InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/innodb/info)

InnoDB supports [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) and [4 Transaction Isolation Levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29)

- [READ-UNCOMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted)
- [READ-COMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-committed)
- [REPEATABLE-READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) (default)
- [SERIALIZABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable)

This allows for INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs, and SELECTs to live harmoniously 99.999% of time

## [MyISAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/myisam/info)

This is a totally different playing field. By default, every INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE locks the entire table. INSERTs can have table locking disabled by setting [concurrent_insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert) to 2. (See [**Concurrent Inserts**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/concurrent-inserts.html) for more information). Otherwise, UPDATEs and DELETEs can still wreak some havoc doing full table locks.

Comment: thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA, I have most of my tables as InnoDB. So, I believe for all practical purposes I will have concurrent READ/WRITES based on your explanation. One table is in MyISAM and I believe I had it that way for adding Full Text Index Search. But, I plan to upgrade MySQL to 5.6 which has support for FTI for InnoDB too