# Inserting data from multiple programs into one table is okay?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-insert

I have 9 python programs running and its inserting data in 9 different tables. All the programs are running simultaneously. All tables have same structure

My question: Is it okay to insert data into one table where multiple programs are running simultaneously and inserting the table into one table. Will I lose some data in this way?

Comment: include relevant code?

Comment: It is okay to do that. In fact, databases excel in that scenario (which is called concurrency). You will not lose data because programs ask MySQL to insert data "at the same time". The reason why data is (usually) lost is because hard disk fails to write the data to permanent storage. TL;DR: it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have lots of client programs inserting data. Doing this while guaranteeing [ACID (atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)  is a core purpose of relational databases.

You may want to read up on [concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637532/concurrent-read-and-write-on-mysql-table) and [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html) if lots of programs are inserting data and others are trying to retrieve it at the same time. Concurrent INSERT and SELECT operations can produce not-quite-intuitive results.  No data is actually lost, but it can seem that way in the moment.

If you just insert many rows, you will have no data-integrity problems at all with concurrent insertions. The MySQL server is designed to solve those problems correctly.

Comment: I dont have ids. just they are like 22 columns and there are web scrapping programs running to extract and insert dat. in this scenario is it fine to do so?

Comment: You will, most likely, have no problems in this scenario. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just inserting data you won't loose anyone but you may have some latency if all programs try to insert in the same time.